# Dependency Injection (DI) in Scala with Play

Tags: scala

I know a few ways to use DI in Scala:

- Cake pattern
- Macwire
  What approach is the most suitable for multi layer application with Play?

I incline to using of macwire in my app.

**UPD**

Solution which fitted for me:
solution of this problem was leveraging of [Macwire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire) lib, but you can combine it with another approaches like pure functional style with `monads` (like [Reader](http://slides.com/danielbedo/reader-monad#/) monad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at my job we use macwire for DI with play and it works smoothly. we used to use cake pattern, but we found that it had more boilerplate than the macwire approach, the compiler errors were harder to interpret, the concept was harder to teach, and cake often triggered full recompiles (whereas we experience much better incremental recompilation with macwire. don't quote me on this one, our switch occurred between 2.10 => 2.11, and i believe there were some improvements from that).

it's hard to answer your question fully though without more details about what you're looking for exactly. care to elaborate?